# Is it possible use nested SUBQUERY in NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, subquery, nspredicate, one-to-many

As you can see I have two one-many relationships. Is it possible to write such a nested SUBQUERY where I want to select all A, where any of the belonging C-s under any of belonging B to A satisfy a certain condition?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can nest SUBQUERY in a predicate. But it seems that a single SUBQUERY is sufficient here (if `ds` is a *to-one* relationship from `C` to `D`), for example

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bs, $x, ANY $x.cs.ds.name = %@).@count > 0", name];
```

Comment: And If I would use the nested SUBQUERY approach, how could I do, why the following give error? SUBQUERY(bs, $B, SUBQUERY(cs, $C, $ds.name != \"xxx\").@count).@count > 0

Comment: @János: It seems that you solved it already in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242383/why-is-wrong-in-my-nested-subquery-predicate.

Comment: @martin: have you work on Realm db, I want to do same thing in realm db but above query is not running there, so If you have some idea regarding this please let me know, thanks in advance

Comment: @PravinTate: I have no experience with Realm, sorry. Perhaps nested queries are not supported, I have no idea.