# What is wrong in my nested SUBQUERY predicate?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate, one-to-many

I have the data model you can see below, and a nested SUBQUERY predicate, but in somehow it just not works. Any idea how to correct it?

I figured out, this here down is working finally:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bs, $B, SUBQUERY($B.cs, $C, $C.ds.name != \"xxx\").@count > 0).@count > 0"];
```

[image]

Comment: So, is it working or not? What is the question?

Comment: If you found the solution to your question, you should add the solution as an answer, instead of editing the question. You can then "accept" your own answer. This way other users can see the problem and the solution, and they know that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so here is the working solution:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bs, $B, SUBQUERY($B.cs, $C, $C.ds.name != \"xxx\").@count > 0).@count > 0"];
```

Comment: Aren't the two the same? What was the problem? How are the two different?

Comment: János's vandalized his own question with his own answer. Initial code was: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bs, $B, SUBQUERY(cs, $C, $C.ds.name != \"xxx\").@count).@count > 0"];` (Lacking `$B.` before `cs` and a ` > 0` after first `@count`.)