# NSPredicate issue for Nested objects IOS

Tags: ios8, nsmutablearray, nsarray, subquery, nspredicate

How can i use `NSPredicate` on "self.tableInfo" (`NSMutableArray`) to get object of `CheckIn` using predicate key "name" with following structure. As self.tableInfo has an array of SectionInfo and every SectionInfo has its cells(CellInfo) inside and each cell has checkin object.

```
- (void)configureView   {
    self.tableInfo = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.filteredTableInfo = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *checkIns =  [CheckIn MR_findAll];
    SectionInfo*checkInSection = [SectionInfo section];
    for (CheckIn *checkIn in checkIns) {
        CellInfo *listCell = (CellInfo *)[CellInfo cell];
        listCell.className = NSStringFromClass([FeedListCell class]);
        listCell.height = 260;
        listCell.object = checkIn;
        [checkInSection.cells addObject:listCell];
    }
    if ([checkIns count] > 0) {
        self.tableInfo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[checkInSection]];
        self.filteredTableInfo = self.tableInfo;
        [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (self.tableInfo) {
        return self.tableInfo.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.tableInfo && (section < self.tableInfo.count) ) {
        SectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.tableInfo objectAtIndex:section];
        return sectionInfo.numberOfCells;
    }
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SectionInfo *sectionInfo = self.tableInfo[indexPath.section];
    CellInfo *formInfoCell = sectionInfo.cells[indexPath.row];
    CheckIn *checkin = formInfoCell.object;
    NSLog(@"%@", checkIn.name);
}
```

The way i am using is something like:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchText];
    }
}
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText   {
    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY cells.object.name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSArray * filteredArray = [self.filteredTableInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate];
    self.tableInfo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[filteredArray]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This returns me always zero count. Any better idea to handle this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple problems with this predicate. First of all, in your predicate you are searching based on "CellInfo.object" `SELF.cells.object contains[c] %@` instead of "CellInfo.object.name" like it seems you want to be doing.

Secondly, when searching an array within an array (in your case SectionInfo.cells within your tableInfo array) you can't simply use dot notation to search the inner array. You have to specify what items you want in the array that match your query. You can do this by using one of the keywords `ANY` `ALL` or `NONE`.

For example, to get any SectionInfo that has a CellInfo whose CheckIn.name contains the search text you would want to do this:

```
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL cells.object.name contains[c] %@", searchText"];
NSArray *filteredSections = [self.tableInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate]
```

However, this returns an array of SectionInfo's instead of CheckIn objects like you wanted. In order to get CheckIn objects instead you must first create an array of all the CheckIn objects first. You can do this by using the `valueForKeyPath` method on NSArray. You can then search that array using a simpler predicate.

```
NSArray *allCheckInObjects = [self.tableInfo valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.cells.object"];
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
NSArray *filteredCheckInObjects = [allCheckInObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried using your approach like: NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL cells.object.name contains[c] %@", searchText]; NSArray *filteredSections = [self.tableInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate]; But result is always an empty array. I need sectionInfo objects.

Comment: Are you certain that self.tableInfo is initialized and populated before you are searching? I would NSLog() the array and make sure you can find the objects you are searching for with the predicate just to be certain that it is indeed the predicate that is failing.

Comment: Yes i have checked it again.Here are my logs while using "Po self.tableInfo" in console and as well as by using NSLog().
 NSLog(@"self.tableInfo before predicate :%@", self.tableInfo);
self.tableInfo before predicate :(
    "<SectionInfo: 0x7c08f900>"
)
NSLog(@"filteredSections :%@", filteredSections);
filteredSections :(
)
NSLog(@"filteredSections array count :%lu", (unsigned long)[filteredSections count]);
filteredSections array count :0

I am sure search key "a" is in my Checkin object.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. I mistakenly specified `ALL` instead of `ANY`. `ALL` requires that every cell within that Section must match the predicate. `ANY` specifies that any cell matching the predicate will suffice. Use `ANY`

Comment: I have used 'ANY' instead of 'ALL'. Now it shows me a sectionInfo object and sectionInfo has zero count of cells inside. Can i do subquery ? Something like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242383/what-is-wrong-in-my-nested-subquery-predicate

Comment: The NSPredicate does not modify the contents of the array it's searching on. Are you doing anything anywhere else to manipulate that sectionInfo? Yes, it is possible to do a subquery; however, it does almost exactly the same thing but is a bit more heavy handed. Subquery is great when you need to check several values of the children (example: object.name contains[c] && object.objectId == @"someId") but otherwise using ANY, ALL, NONE is preferred.

Comment: Could you possibly provide some more code so I can better see what's going on?

Comment: Yeah sure. Please review my edited question. Please let me know, if you need something more from me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve by following code. i had "Recent" and "Other" array in single array i apply predicate in each array. and search criteria was "name" in "from_user" NSDictionary.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self.filterResultArray removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(from_user.name contains[cd] %@)", searchText];

    NSMutableArray *recentSearch=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //Recent
    if ([[[self connectioUserArray] objectAtIndex:1] count]==0) {
        //Recent is blank
    }
    else{
        //else
        recentSearch=[[[[self connectioUserArray] objectAtIndex:0] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate] mutableCopy];
    }

    //other
    self.filterResultArray = [[[[self connectioUserArray] objectAtIndex:1] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate] mutableCopy];

    if ([recentSearch count]==0) {
        //no records
    }
    else{
        //if recent records
        for (NSMutableDictionary *recentConnectoin in recentSearch) {
            [self.filterResultArray addObject:recentConnectoin];
        }
    }

    //Reload table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```