# Use NSExpression CAST with NSPredicate in Core Data

Tags: core-data, casting, ios7, nspredicate, nsexpression

My problem is exactly the same as you can read in this thread:
[stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224601/is-it-possible-use-nested-subquery-in-nspredicate)

But there is a small difference. I try to explain it using the above thread's image.
The CS relationship contains `C` type objects as it is described, but also contains `E` type objects too, because the `E` type objects are derived from the `C` type object.

On thread's image the `E` type object is not present and this is the difference. The `E` type property also has a `CS` relationship.

The problem comes when I try to reach the `E` type object's `CS` property using the following query: `SUBQUERY(bs, $x, ANY $x.cs.cs ....`

The query is not finished, but the important code is there. As I observed, the predicate creation fails, because it tries to use the `CS` relationship on the `C` type object. I've tried to use the `CAST` operator on the `$x.cs` variable without success.

Do anybody has a clue for this?

---

Edit: Added image
[image]

The `values` of the `MKMultiAttribute` entity can contain `MKAttribute` and `MKMultiAttribute` types. And this is the problem, because the `values` is set to be a relationship to `MKAttribute`, but, because `MKMultiAttribute` is derived from `MKAttribute` the `values` can contain `MKMultiAttribute` entities and currently I can't call the `values` again.

Comment: Is the relationship C<-->E like C<-->D, one-to-one?

Comment: C doesn't connect to E, B connects to E or C. So the Relation is B<-->C or B <--> E and both of them are one-to-many. After this C or E connects to D, but E may also connect to more C or E which can also connect to D. I hope this way the problem is more clear.

Comment: Can you add an image of your model?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to fetch?

Comment: multiAttributes.values.values.value contains[c] "someString"